# String comparison fails with varchar variable

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm having trouble with understanding why I get the results below:

```
declare @myVar1 varchar = 'Friday'
declare @myVar2 varchar(10) = 'Friday'

select 
  case when @myVar1 = 'Friday' then 'yes' else 'no' end as test1,
  case when @myVar2 = 'Friday' then 'yes' else 'no' end as test2,
  case when @myVar1 = @myVar2 then 'yes' else 'no' end as test3
```

What I get is:

```
test1: no 
test2: yes 
test3: no
```

Why does the string comparison fail if the varchar is declared without the (optional) size?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: Agree that it's a bad habit - but why does it fail?

Comment: Ah - sorry, didn't see that your comment was actually a link. Thanks for posting the more detailed answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/4737

```
declare @myVar1 varchar = 'Friday'
declare @myVar2 varchar(10) = 'Friday'

select len(@myVar1)as len1,
       len(@myVar2)as len2
```

Result is:

```
LEN1       LEN2
1           6
```

So if you don't specify a size for the `varchar`, SQL Server will do it for you. In this case 1. You should always specify the size explicitly.

[Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)