# VARCHAR comparison in the FUNCTION

Tags: sql-server, compare, varchar

I have the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ISRELKDVG(@WUNSCH_LIEFERTERMIN VARCHAR) RETURNS int AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sTerminNone VARCHAR(8)
    DECLARE @sTerminFrom VARCHAR(8)
    SET @sTerminNone = '00000000'
    SET @sTerminFrom = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE() - 100, 112) -- 100 days in the past
    IF (@WUNSCH_LIEFERTERMIN <> @sTerminNone AND @WUNSCH_LIEFERTERMIN >= @sTerminFrom)
        RETURN 1
    RETURN 0
END
```

The variable given as parameter to the function is a date and has a form "YYYYMMDD". The problem is that the function never returns 1.

I have found the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090400/string-comparison-fails-with-varchar-variable) which says that comparing varchar's with unspecified length may lead to errors. Does it also refer to varchar's passed to the functions?

Answer (score 0):

Do not rely on implicit conversions, using unknown dateformats. Convert to dates or datetimes, specifying a dateformat, and compare those values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is the main problem.

**[MSDN - Remarks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)**

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified when using
>   the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

But (even in case of Cast/Convert), you should always define the length to avoid such troubles.

Change

```
@WUNSCH_LIEFERTERMIN VARCHAR --<--Length is 1 by default
```

To

```
@WUNSCH_LIEFERTERMIN VARCHAR(8) --Or length as appropriate
```

Secondly, you should be comparing `Dates` *not* `Strings`.

```
DECLARE @sTerminNone DATE = CONVERT(DATETIME, 0) --<--DATE (Assign correct date)
DECLARE @sTerminFrom DATE = GETDATE() - 100
```

Finally,

```
IF (CONVERT(DATE, @WUNSCH_LIEFERTERMIN, 112) <> @sTerminNone AND --Not sure if you need this
    CONVERT(DATE, @WUNSCH_LIEFERTERMIN, 112) >= @sTerminFrom)
    RETURN 1
ELSE
    RETURN 0
```

Ideally, you should pass/define a `DateType parameter` to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the size of function parameter, e.g. varchar(8). Otherwise it is 1 character long by default:

```
declare @c as varchar
set @c = '20130101'
select @c -- returns 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ISRELKDVG(@WUNSCH_LIEFERTERMIN VARCHAR(8)) RETURNS int AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sTerminNone VARCHAR(8)
    DECLARE @sTerminFrom DATE
    SET @sTerminNone = '00000000'

    IF (@WUNSCH_LIEFERTERMIN = @sTerminNone)
        RETURN 0

    SET @sTerminFrom = DATEADD(day,-100,GETDATE()) -- 100 days in the past
    IF (CAST(@WUNSCH_LIEFERTERMIN AS DATE) >= @sTerminFrom)
        RETURN 1

    RETURN 0          
END

select dbo.ISRELKDVG('00000000') --0
select dbo.ISRELKDVG('20030901') --0
select dbo.ISRELKDVG('20130901') --1
select dbo.ISRELKDVG('20130730') --1
```